# Android AsyncTask strangely publishing duplicates

Tags: android, synchronize

I think this is not an easy question.
I'll be brief and give a little example of what is happening.
Let's say we have a source of data in file Byron.txt:

> SHE walks in beauty, like the night
>   Of cloudless climes and starry skies;
>   And all that 's best of dark and bright
>   Meet in her aspect and her eyes:
>   Thus mellow'd to that tender light
>   Which heaven to gaudy day denies.

And this code execute inside an AsyncTask:

```js
final ArrayList<Record> poem = new ArrayList<Record>();
final Object objectLock = new Object();
private Record rec = new Record();

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
    String line = null;
    int i;
    int last;

    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat Byron.txt");
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()), 8192);

        synchronized (objectLock) {
            poem.clear();
            last = i = poem.size() - 1;
        }
        while(line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            rec.setString(line);
            synchronized (objectLock) {
                last++;
                poem.add(last, rec);
            }

            while(!bPause && i < last) {
                i++;
                publishProgress(poem.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onProgressUpdate(Record... m) {
    if(m.length > 0) {
        mContext.mTable.appendRow(m[0]);
    }

}
```

where there is a TableLayout in the UI and each time we get a new line we add a new TableRow to it.
And this is the output we see in the UI:

> SHE walks in beauty, like the night
>   Of cloudless climes and starry skies;
>   Of cloudless climes and starry skies;
>   Of cloudless climes and starry skies;
>   Thus mellow'd to that tender light
>   Thus mellow'd to that tender light

And we go into the debugger and we see why it happens.
Sometimes the `synchronized (objectLock)` is skipped and the loop continues.
There is no publishing because `i` already catched `last`.
Later the block is executed as many times as it was skipped,
, but the original line is lost and the current line is added instead to `poem` several times
Then, all the new lines are published until `i` catches `last` again.

So you see that I followed the code and I can explain what's happening, the question here is: **Why the block is skipped?, Why?**
I expected the synchronized block to stall until it can be executed.
At least this how I understood the function of `synchronized (objectLock)`
even without using `wait()` and `notify()`

I don't pretend to open a discussion here (although if you want we can open one in the chat area) 
If you see some fault in the code, then, answer the question to let me know.

**NOTES:**

1. `synchronized` is needed because somewhere else in the app, the user may want to email the lines he got so far.
2. The user may pause the publishing (`bpause`); that's the `while` loop and `i` follows `last` only when `bPause` is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to publish the answer. Even though I feel very *embarrassed* by its simplicity.
I discovered it only after I had already dug deep into `AsyncTask` class and message handling and whatnot.

> I publish it in hope it will help people to check the basic things before jumping to
>   conclusions, and that someone out there will save himself half a day debugging because of
>   this post.

The `Record rec` was the same one each time. The `poem` ArrayList had the same element id for each entry. And the content changed on all of them at once, since they were all the same.
When the progress was published immediately it printed the right string, the last one. But if some delay cause the progress to publish later, then retrieving the `poem.get(i)` records retrieved a different entry but with the same pointer, thus, the same content.

**The solution was to create a new Record each loop.**

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer. Most ppl dont care adding the answer if they find it themselves. And nothing to be embarrassed about, such things happen once in a while to all programmers..

Answer (score 0):

Do the synchronization for `last` object.

```
synchronized (last) {
   last++;
   poem.add(last, line);
}
```

Comment: So far, it is not making any difference, I'll keep debugging

Comment: try sync on last object.. make last Integer if necesary